# stub out new call for js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I would like to stub out a library I am using, which I instantiate with a `new` call, however, I have not been able to find how to do this. This is the specific line I am talking about: https://github.com/reviewninja/review.ninja/blob/f8717690aeb1288e668f835d36bcabe7e6b21b0c/src/server/services/github.js#L11 I want to stub out that call to be able to check if my service interacts correctly with the library. Any idea how to do that? The problem is not stubbing out itself, stubbing out any other function on an object is no problem with sinon, however the new call seems to be special.

Comment: The `new` call is not special.  What have you tried? What happened? Are you actually asking how to stub a `require`d value?

Comment: well I can't as usual just do sinon.stub(GitHubApi, 'new', function(){}); ... stubbing out the required value would also work I guess

Comment: You need to stub the function itself.  `new` is just a different way of calling.